# Dynamic Programming : Timus Online Judge 1172 Ship Routes

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have been stuck on this problem from a long time. It must have a dynamic programming solution as it has been tagged as "dynammic programming". Please suggest an approach.

> [Question Link](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1172)

Abridged problem statement:

> There are 3 islands having N cities on each of them. There is a path from every city on an island to every city on another island, ie. there is no path connecting cities on the same island. Find the number of ways of visiting all the 3*N cities. Note that 2 trips are identical if the successions of the 3*N cities are identical or if the succession of the 3*N cities of the first trip is the same as the succession of the 3*N cities of the 2nd trip, read backwards (for instance, if every island had 1 city, numbered according to the island's number, the trips 1-2-3-1 and 1-3-2-1 would be identical).

Constraints:

> 1 ≤ N ≤ 30

Sample Input/Output:

> For N=2, answer = 16.

Comment: What approaches / solutions have you come up with thus far?.. and people might be able to direct you from there.

Comment: I believe you mean "Find the number of ways of visiting all the 3N cities", not "N"? Of course the additional constraint that you start from one of them and must return to it at the end must also hold.

Comment: @lightalchemist Yes, I mean visiting 3N cities in a loop. I have edited the question.

Comment: @lzcd I have tried a dp solution in which states are defined on the basis of how many cities are left in each of the islands and which island we are currently on. I am solving each of these (30^3)*3 problems in constant time by going to another island and changing the problem state accordingly. But in this duplicate paths will be counted and is wrong.

Comment: @NikunjBanka How can you tell how many cities and which are left with only 30*3 states?

Comment: @PhamTrung The approach I have just mentioned is just an intuition and defining the states this way clearly doesn't solve my problem. I cant think of any other way to approach the problem.

Comment: @NikunjBanka the answer is not fit long range? 30! is definitely very large?

Comment: you can use a BigInteger or answer module 10^9+7. I am just looking for the algorithm and the approach that will work in less than 1 second when n=30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just my idea:

First, we can solve the problem if we can solve two subproblems

- Assume that you need to generate a string with length 3*N made **only from  1 , 2 or 3** , count how many ways we can create this string, with the condition that there is **no 2 consecutive occurrences** of 1, 2 or 3, and for each type of character, there should be N of them in the string. You can solve this using DP
- Secondly, from all the string created, removed the first character, because of the condition that string can be read equally backward and forward, so each string will be counted twice, **except palindrome**. so , we need to count the number of palindrome for those 3*N - 1 string. This can be solved by DP

And, now, we can replace each position of 1,2 or 3 in the string with one city in island 1, 2 or 3  and there is (N!)^3 way to do that for each string , and we have the answer

Comment: Mostly right, but I think that (including duplicates) there are (N-1)!N!N! ways to assign distinct cities to island visits, because each island's cities can be independently assigned.

Comment: Another thought: There are no palindromes, because each city is visited once only :)  We just need a constraint like "Only count paths in which the first city visited is lower-numbered than the last city visited", but it's complicated because the first and last cities could be on the same island or on different islands.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Actually the length of the string should be 3*N + 1, with the first and last character is the same , so I think it need to be fixed somehow :D

Comment: We can ignore the first and last character, which must be 1, and consider only sequences of islands of length 3N-1 in which neither the first nor the last character are 1, and in which there are N-1 1s in total, N 2s and N 3s.

Comment: ... and in which no digit appears twice in a row, as you said.

Comment: @j_random_hacker yes, you're right, I just edited to improve the answer

Comment: Here is one way to avoid counting "reflected" paths: Count only those paths that meet the following additional restriction: Either they begin with island 2 and end with island 3, OR they begin and end with the same digit (=island), and the city assigned to the first-visited island is less than the city assigned to the last-visited island. This works because every path either satisfies this constraint, or its reflection satisfies it, but never both.  Not sure exactly how to implement this yet, but I think it is conceptually correct.

Comment: @j_random_hacker ha ha, the condition is ok, but i think it will be harder to implement a DP solution based on that